# Weird test error xcode 7

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, cocoapods, xcode7

Hi there has anyone encountered this issue, while running test with xcode 7? Whenever I run my test, it's failing with the following error:

```
<GMR/INFO> App measurement v.1100000 started
Failure to configure[].
Subspecs not present, so not configured [Analytics, AdMob, AppInvite, CloudMessaging, Maps].
Subspecs expected to be present [SignIn, Measurement].
The bundle “my-project” couldn’t be loaded because its executable couldn’t be located. Try reinstalling the bundle.
```

That's my podfile;

```
target 'my-project' do

    pod 'SwiftyJSON'

    pod 'Alamofire'

    pod 'AFNetworking'

    source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

     pod 'AWSCore', '= 2.1.2'

    pod 'AWSS3', '= 2.1.2'

    pod 'SwiftValidator'

    pod 'RavenSwift'

    pod 'KAProgressLabel'

    pod 'Google/SignIn'

    pod 'IOSLinkedInAPI'

    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.6'

    end



target 'my-projectTests', :exclusive => true do

    pod 'SwiftyJSON'

    pod 'Alamofire'

    pod 'AFNetworking'


    source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

    pod 'AWSCore', '= 2.1.2'

    pod 'AWSS3', '= 2.1.2'

    pod 'SwiftValidator'

    pod 'RavenSwift'

    pod 'KAProgressLabel'    

    pod 'Google/SignIn'

    pod 'IOSLinkedInAPI'

    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.6'

end
```

I have tried to find an answer on google, but without success.
Any help will really be welcomed

Comment: Are you using CocoaPods? Have you added the correct specs to your test target?

Comment: yes i'm using cocoapods. i'm new into iOS, what do you mean by 'Have you added the correct specs to your test target? '

Comment: Maybe you should post your podfile

Comment: I've edited the question and added the podilfe description

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XCTest: The bundle “target Tests” couldn’t be loaded because its executable couldn’t be located](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29662266/xctest-the-bundle-target-tests-couldn-t-be-loaded-because-its-executable-coul)

Comment: I get the same issue - but no resolution so far using Cocoapods